# plotting 3d density plot for y

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have three covariates [x1, x2, x3] and one y . I want to plot a 3d density plot of y which is obtained using these these three covariates (like a linear regression). I am wondering if this is possible ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for how to do the impossible. Wanting to do it in R is a detail.

Comment: @NickCox, I don't see this as impossible. We have lots of questions about visualizing 4D data. I don't think this is very different. Certainly it is possible to *compute* such densities, as to visualizing them, I would use level curves with a coplot.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `persp` function. An example is given below from the base graphics package:

```
z <- 2 * volcano        # Exaggerate the relief
x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z))   # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z))   # 10 meter spacing (E to W)
par(bg = "slategray")
persp(x, y, z, theta = 135, phi = 30, col = "green3", scale = FALSE,
      ltheta = -120, shade = 0.75, border = NA, box = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but recognize that the OP has **3** `x` variables. You might want to see if you can marry this approach to a coplot, or some similar solution.